# The Minimal Commitment: Upvoting Questions and Answers

Tags: support

Hey guys,

Just wanted to remind everybody that the minimum you can do to support the site is *read questions, and upvote good questions and answers.*

This is not really hard to do; everybody on the site has some type of questions they find interesting (for me, agile/scrum/IT + risk management); so read and upvote!

I know sometimes people get caught into the "reputation trap" of focusing purely on reputation -- reading only questions they might know, dropping answers, and not up-voting other good answers -- but in the **spirit of project management, be fair to everyone, even people who you're "competing" against.**

My personal time availability is fluctuating, so this is a reminder to myself first and to the rest of us -- voting is easy and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement!  I plan to spend some time this weekend to read some previously asked questions and vote on some good questions and answers.

Comment: Are there 'signs' that there isn't enough upvoting? And what does that mean, then, for the site?

Comment: @Stephan there is; see the Area 51 Proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management -- there's a section on "avid users;" we're on track for 2000+ and 3000+ rep users (moderate: yellow), but for 150+ rep, we're behind and going to end with a worrying/red metric.

Comment: Ashes, thanks for the link. That's indeed "worrying" if we're going to get judged by those stats. Number of visitors is maybe the most worrying of all.

Comment: @Stephan there are a couple other threads discussing this; notably: http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/94/site-not-on-track-to-survive-public-beta -- I wouldn't worry overly much; if you can, blog/write about the site, and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, "Vote Early and Often"!

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/
https://pm.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters

Beyond that:

1. Share great questions and answers
   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/
2. Love and reward your new users for being awesome! (hint: also involves voting!)
   https://pm.stackexchange.com/review
   https://pm.stackexchange.com/users
3. Try to attract experts to the site by helping them get answers, too:
   http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/